# Why PHP SDK for facebook returns different data while login in core php code and cakephp code

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I develop an application through which user can log in with Facebook.
Same application i have develop in core php and in cakephp.

**below are my core php code**

```
$Fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_KEY,  /// app key is defined
    'secret' => SECREATE_KEY // secret key is defined
));

$session = $Fb->getUser();

////   These are perimission   you want to receive from facebook   
if (!$session) {
    $params = array(
        'scope'  => "user_about_me,user_location,user_hometown,user_birthday,email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos,friends_photos,friends_about_me,read_friendlists,",
        'redirect_uri'       => HTTP_ROOT.'fb-login.php',
        'cancel_url' => HTTP_ROOT.'index.php?fb-cancel'
    );
    header("location:".$Fb->getLoginUrl($params));
    die;
}

$Fb->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();

$userInfo = $Fb->api('/me');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($userInfo);
```

**The print_r() returns are as follows:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 893539037328964
    [birthday] => 12/16/1987
    [email] => psanjib.tutu@gmail.com
    [first_name] => Sanjib
    [gender] => male
    [hometown] => Array
        (
            [id] => 106495832719066
            [name] => Cuttack, Orissa
        )

    [last_name] => Pradhan
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/psanjib16
    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 113013885382461
            [name] => Bhubaneshwar, Orissa, India
        )

    [locale] => en_US
    [name] => Sanjib Pradhan
    [timezone] => 5.5
    [updated_time] => 2014-04-16T03:30:09+0000
    [username] => psanjib16
    [verified] => 1
)
```

**Below are my cakephp code**

```
App::import('Vendor', 'facebook/facebook');
        $Fb = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_KEY,
            'secret' => SECREATE_KEY
        ));

    $session = $Fb->getUser();
    if (!$session) {
        $params = array(
            'scope'  => "user_about_me,user_location,user_hometown,user_birthday,email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos,friends_photos,friends_about_me,read_friendlists,",
            'cancel_url' => HTTP_ROOT . 'awareds/?fb-cancel'
        );

        header("location:" . $Fb->getLoginUrl($params));
        //$this->redirect(HTTP_ROOT . 'awards/index/');
        die;
    }


    $Fb->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
    $userInfo = $Fb->api('/me'); 
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($userInfo); exit;
```

**the print_r() for cakephp return are as follows**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 889910627691805
    [email] => psanjib.tutu@gmail.com
    [first_name] => Sanjib
    [gender] => male
    [last_name] => Pradhan
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/889910627691805/
    [locale] => en_US
    [name] => Sanjib Pradhan
    [timezone] => 5.5
    [updated_time] => 2014-04-16T03:30:09+0000
    [verified] => 1
)
```

mark the above two output
the core php code return 3 extra out put that is

hometown, location, username

why different out put, is there any reason.
i want username should come on cakephp return

thanks,
Sanjib

Answer (score 0):

I think your lacking something on your scope, here is my scope in cakePHP:

```
'scope' => array('public_profile','publish_actions','email', 'user_likes') //maybe you are missing public_profile scope
```

This is what my $this->Facebook->api('/me') results (I deleted the data values though but the keys are there, including the username):

http://pastebin.com/wRM44zLM

Comment: @psanjib have you checked this?